# R reactable format multiple columns as percentage

Tags: r, reactable

I'd like format several columns in my dataframe as percentage with reactable package. I know how can I do it if I specify all of them row by row, but I'd like to achieve same output only if I specify starting column number, in this case from 2nd column.

```
reactable(
  data.frame(
    id = seq(1, 10, 1),
    sh = seq(.1, 1, .1),
    ar = seq(.1, 1, .1),
    br = seq(.1, 1, .1)
  ), 
  columns = list(
    sh = colDef(format = colFormat(percent = TRUE, digits = 1)),
    ar = colDef(format = colFormat(percent = TRUE, digits = 1)),
    br = colDef(format = colFormat(percent = TRUE, digits = 1))
    )
  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to use e.g. `lapply` to create a named list of `colDef`s:

```
library(reactable)

dat <- data.frame(
  id = seq(1, 10, 1),
  sh = seq(.1, 1, .1),
  ar = seq(.1, 1, .1),
  br = seq(.1, 1, .1)
)

cols <- names(dat)[-1]
col_defs <- lapply(
  cols,
  \(x) colDef(format = colFormat(percent = TRUE, digits = 1))
)
names(col_defs) <- cols

reactable(
  dat,
  columns = col_defs
)
```

[image]